# How to publish my app on marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace, appsource

I want to know where I can get data in order to know hot to integrate my app with the azure marketplace/appSource. My idea is to do it as a transact application but I am not able to find any documentation on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the answer from the [Marketplace FAQs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/faq/).

> Please visit https://azure.microsoft.com/marketplace/programs/certified/ to learn more about the Microsoft Azure Certified program and how to publish and sell your applications and services in the Azure Marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

For AppSource, there is a Getting Started Guide and detailed steps on how you can setup your application to fulfill the requirements for AppSource listing and test drive on Microsoft's AppSource GitHub repository as shown below.

[AppSource Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppSource/blob/master/GettingStarted.md)